# Definition of the Coefficients of a Quadratic Polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hey guys I have a pretty straight forward question that I was wondering about.

Would $c$ in the following equation be considered a coefficient and constant or just a constant?

$f(x)= ax^2+bx+c$.

The reason why I would think it to be a coefficient is because,

$f(x)= ax^2+bx+c= ax^2+bx+cx^0$.

Thus, I would want to claim that $c$ is the coefficient of the term $x^0$

Also, I don't think I've ever encountered a formal definition of "coefficient". However, I am only a sophomore in college so that might be the reason why.

Thanks for the feedback in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's the coefficient of $x^0$. Note that all the coefficients are constants too, because they don't change their value.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot just needed a little clarification!

Comment: It is a *coefficient*. It is also the *constant term*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comments by  [user164587](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/164587/user164587) and [André](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6312/andr%C3%A9-nicolas), $c$ can be interpreted as the coefficient of the term $x^0$. It is also called the constant term.